# How to Create href Download Links to Files with Arbitrary Extensions

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have files of varying extensions that I create download links to in a Razor Page View. For example:

```
<a href="@Model.DownloadFile.FilePath" download="@Model.FileDownloadName" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Download</a>
```

this works for files that end in .md or .txt. But for other extensions I receive

> Failed - No file

upon downloading in chrome. When browsing the file directly I receive 404.

Upon inspection of the element it does show the proper path and as I said, if I change the extension it works but I do not want users to have to rename the downloaded file to the appropriate extension.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Razor Pages and Bootstrap. My download directory is placed in the `wwwroot` folder and I do have `app.UseStaticFiles();` in my Configure method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serving unknown file types is a bad idea. It's a security risk, and even the documentation warns you against using it. If the file extension(s) you need to serve are known, then you should add mime type mappings for them instead:

```
services.Configure<StaticFileOptions>(o =>
{
    var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

    // Repeat this for each extension you need to map.
    provider.Mappings[".foo"] = "text/plain";

    o.ContentTypeProvider = provider;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The list of possible extensions is quite long but still finite so I will use this approach. Originally I didn't mind serving up every file type as my project is only meant to run on a local network for personal use and is not intended to be deployed to a remote server, but it is worth handling things properly regardless of that.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by modying my Configure method from

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

to

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true,
            DefaultContentType = "image/png"
        });
```

More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#non-standard-content-types

Comment: Be careful with that. First, the `DefaultContentType` needs to be something that generally matches what you're going to be serving. Using this with `image/png` and then serving up Excel docs is going to cause problems. Second, it's a security risk, the files your willing to serve should be explicitly numerated. Serving *anything* opens up a significant attack vector. Assuming the extensions aren't just entirely random, it's better to explicitly add them as additional mime types.